# Symfony2: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I got this error when updating a product: (updating a category is ok)

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted
>   to string in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator.php
>   line 188

[image]

[image]

**Full stack trace:**

```
Stack Trace
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator.php at line 188   -
            $this->loadCatalogue($locale);
        }
        return strtr($this->catalogues[$locale]->get((string) $id, $domain), $parameters);
    }
    /**
at ErrorHandler ->handle ('4096', 'Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator.php', '188', array('id' => 'This value should be blank.', 'parameters' => array('{{ value }}' => object(DateTime)), 'domain' => 'validators', 'locale' => 'en')) 
at strtr ('This value should be blank.', array('{{ value }}' => object(DateTime))) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator.php at line 188   + 
at Translator ->trans ('This value should be blank.', array('{{ value }}' => object(DateTime)), 'validators') 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext.php at line 93   + 
at ExecutionContext ->addViolation ('This value should be blank.', array('{{ value }}' => object(DateTime))) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\BlankValidator.php at line 30   + 
at BlankValidator ->validate (object(DateTime), object(Blank)) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext.php at line 276   + 
at ExecutionContext ->executeConstraintValidators (object(DateTime), array(object(Blank))) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext.php at line 241   + 
at ExecutionContext ->validateValue (object(DateTime), array(object(Blank))) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidationVisitor.php at line 110   + 
at ValidationVisitor ->visit (object(PropertyMetadata), object(DateTime), 'Default', 'data.created_at') 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\MemberMetadata.php at line 47   + 
at MemberMetadata ->accept (object(ValidationVisitor), object(DateTime), 'Default', 'data.created_at', null) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata.php at line 114   + 
at ClassMetadata ->accept (object(ValidationVisitor), object(Product), 'Default', 'data') 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidationVisitor.php at line 162   + 
at ValidationVisitor ->validate (object(Product), 'Default', 'data', true, false) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext.php at line 227   + 
at ExecutionContext ->validate (object(Product), 'data', 'Default', true) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\Constraints\FormValidator.php at line 60   + 
at FormValidator ->validate (object(Form), object(Form)) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext.php at line 276   + 
at ExecutionContext ->executeConstraintValidators (object(Form), array(object(Form))) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext.php at line 241   + 
at ExecutionContext ->validateValue (object(Form), array(object(Form))) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidationVisitor.php at line 110   + 
at ValidationVisitor ->visit (object(ClassMetadata), object(Form), 'Default', '') 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata.php at line 107   + 
at ClassMetadata ->accept (object(ValidationVisitor), object(Form), 'Default', '') 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidationVisitor.php at line 162   + 
at ValidationVisitor ->validate (object(Form), 'Default', '', false, false) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator.php at line 90   + 
at Validator ->validate (object(Form)) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\EventListener\ValidationListener.php at line 55   + 
at ValidationListener ->validateForm (object(FormEvent)) 
at call_user_func (array(object(ValidationListener), 'validateForm'), object(FormEvent)) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\app\cache\dev\classes.php at line 1655   + 
at EventDispatcher ->doDispatch (array(array(object(ValidationListener), 'validateForm')), 'form.post_bind', object(FormEvent)) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\app\cache\dev\classes.php at line 1588   + 
at EventDispatcher ->dispatch ('form.post_bind', object(FormEvent)) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ImmutableEventDispatcher.php at line 42   + 
at ImmutableEventDispatcher ->dispatch ('form.post_bind', object(FormEvent)) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php at line 624   + 
at Form ->submit (object(Request)) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php at line 638   + 
at Form ->bind (object(Request)) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\src\Mobile\BusinessBundle\Controller\ProductController.php at line 132   + 
at ProductController ->updateAction (object(Request), '7') 
at call_user_func_array (array(object(ProductController), 'updateAction'), array(object(Request), '7')) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 2770   + 
at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1') 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 2744   + 
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 2874   + 
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\app\bootstrap.php.cache at line 2175   + 
at Kernel ->handle (object(Request)) 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\web\app_dev.php at line 29   +
```

Here is the code:
**Product.php**

```
<?php

namespace Mobile\BusinessBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Lib\Functions;

/**
* Product
*/
class Product
{

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $slug;

/**
 * @var float
 */
private $price;

/**
 * @var float
 */
private $discount;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $detail;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $sku;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $views;

/**
 * @var boolean
 */
private $is_active;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $created_at;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $updated_at;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $categories;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Product
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set slug
 *
 * @param string $slug
 * @return Product
 */
public function setSlug($slug)
{
    $this->slug = $slug;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get slug
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSlug()
{
    return $this->slug;
}

/**
 * Set price
 *
 * @param float $price
 * @return Product
 */
public function setPrice($price)
{
    $this->price = $price;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get price
 *
 * @return float 
 */
public function getPrice()
{
    return $this->price;
}

/**
 * Set discount
 *
 * @param float $discount
 * @return Product
 */
public function setDiscount($discount)
{
    $this->discount = $discount;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get discount
 *
 * @return float 
 */
public function getDiscount()
{
    return $this->discount;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 * @return Product
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set detail
 *
 * @param string $detail
 * @return Product
 */
public function setDetail($detail)
{
    $this->detail = $detail;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get detail
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDetail()
{
    return $this->detail;
}

/**
 * Set sku
 *
 * @param string $sku
 * @return Product
 */
public function setSku($sku)
{
    $this->sku = $sku;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get sku
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSku()
{
    return $this->sku;
}

/**
 * Set views
 *
 * @param integer $views
 * @return Product
 */
public function setViews($views)
{
    $this->views = $views;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get views
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getViews()
{
    return $this->views;
}

/**
 * Set is_active
 *
 * @param boolean $isActive
 * @return Product
 */
public function setIsActive($isActive)
{
    $this->is_active = $isActive;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get is_active
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getIsActive()
{
    return $this->is_active;
}

/**
 * Set created_at
 *
 * @param \DateTime $createdAt
 * @return Product
 */
public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
{
    $this->created_at = $createdAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get created_at
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getCreatedAt()
{
    return $this->created_at;
}

/**
 * Set updated_at
 *
 * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
 * @return Product
 */
public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
{
    $this->updated_at = $updatedAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get updated_at
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getUpdatedAt()
{
    return $this->updated_at;
}

/**
 * Add categories
 *
 * @param \Mobile\BusinessBundle\Entity\Category $categories
 * @return Product
 */
public function addCategorie(\Mobile\BusinessBundle\Entity\Category $categories)
{
    $this->categories[] = $categories;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove categories
 *
 * @param \Mobile\BusinessBundle\Entity\Category $categories
 */
public function removeCategorie(\Mobile\BusinessBundle\Entity\Category $categories)
{
    $this->categories->removeElement($categories);
}

/**
 * Get categories
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getCategories()
{
    return $this->categories;
}
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function onPrePersist()
{
    $this->created_at = new \DateTime();
    $this->updated_at = new \DateTime();
    $this->views = 0;
    $this->is_active = true;
    $this->slug = Functions::url_friendly($this->name);
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function onPreUpdate()
{
    $this->updated_at = new \DateTime();
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->name;
}
}
```

**Product.orm.yml**

```
Mobile\BusinessBundle\Entity\Product:
type: entity
repositoryClass: Mobile\BusinessBundle\Entity\ProductRepository
manyToMany:
    categories:
        targetEntity: Category
        inversedBy: products
table: products
fields:
    id:
        type: bigint
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
    name:
        type: string
        length: 255
    slug:
        type: string
        length: 255
    price:
        type: decimal
        length: null
    discount:
        type: decimal
        length: null
    description:
        type: text
        length: null
    detail:
        type: text
        length: null
    sku:
        type: string
        length: 45
    views:
        type: bigint
    is_active:
        type: boolean
    created_at:
        type: datetime
    updated_at:
        type: datetime
lifecycleCallbacks:
  prePersist: [onPrePersist]
  preUpdate: [onPreUpdate]
```

**ProductType.php**

```
<?php

namespace Mobile\BusinessBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('slug')
        ->add('price')
        ->add('discount')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('detail')
        ->add('sku')
        ->add('views')
        ->add('is_active')
        ->add('created_at')
        ->add('updated_at')
        ->add('categories')
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Mobile\BusinessBundle\Entity\Product'
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'mobile_businessbundle_producttype';
}
}
```

**ProductController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Mobile\BusinessBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Mobile\BusinessBundle\Entity\Product;
use Mobile\BusinessBundle\Form\ProductType;

/**
 * Product controller.
 *
 */
class ProductController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Lists all Product entities.
 *
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('MobileBusinessBundle:Product')->findAll();

    return $this->render('MobileBusinessBundle:Product:index.html.twig', array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    ));
}
/**
 * Creates a new Product entity.
 *
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity  = new Product();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $entity);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('product_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return $this->render('MobileBusinessBundle:Product:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}

/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Product entity.
 *
 */
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new Product();
    $form   = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $entity);

    return $this->render('MobileBusinessBundle:Product:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}

/**
 * Finds and displays a Product entity.
 *
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('MobileBusinessBundle:Product')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Product entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return $this->render('MobileBusinessBundle:Product:show.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),        ));
}

/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Product entity.
 *
 */
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('MobileBusinessBundle:Product')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Product entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return $this->render('MobileBusinessBundle:Product:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}

/**
 * Edits an existing Product entity.
 *
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('MobileBusinessBundle:Product')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Product entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $entity);
    $editForm->bind($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('product_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return $this->render('MobileBusinessBundle:Product:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
/**
 * Deletes a Product entity.
 *
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('MobileBusinessBundle:Product')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Product entity.');
        }

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('product'));
}

/**
 * Creates a form to delete a Product entity by id.
 *
 * @param mixed $id The entity id
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createDeleteForm($id)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder(array('id' => $id))
        ->add('id', 'hidden')
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
}
```

**edit.html.twig**

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body -%}
    <h1>Product edit</h1>

    <form action="{{ path('product_update', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(edit_form) }}>
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
        {{ form_widget(edit_form) }}
        <p>
            <button type="submit">Edit</button>
        </p>
    </form>

        <ul class="record_actions">
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('product') }}">
            Back to the list
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <form action="{{ path('product_delete', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
            {{ form_widget(delete_form) }}
            <button type="submit">Delete</button>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

**Updated:**
The error occurred because I created the file validation.yml for the Product Entity with created_at : Blank.
    Mobile\BusinessBundle\Entity\Product:
        properties:
            created_at:
                - Blank: ~

Comment: do you have the intl extension on ?

Comment: @mpm: Yes, I have used it.

Comment: please show full error stack trace

Comment: @forgottenbas: I added the full stack trace into the topic. Please see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like problems in your validators. Possible that is `validators.yml` cause I dont see validation annotations on entity.  You trying to validate DateTime with `NotBlank` validator which trying to show you error. Change it to `NotNull` validator.

```
'C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator.php', '188', array('id' => 'This value should be blank.', 'parameters' => array('{{ value }}' => object(DateTime)), 'domain' => 'validators', 'locale' => 'en')) 
at strtr ('This value should be blank.', array('{{ value }}' => object(DateTime)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It's exactly the error here. I've created the validation.yml for the Product entity and set the created_at with Blank: ~. So it causes the error when updating the product.

My issue has been solved. Thank you.

Comment: glad that can help you :)